# How to use pdb correctly without executing the whole file first

Tags: python, pdb

This is my .pdbrc file contents:

```
b 2
c
```

This is my code.py contents:

```
print('1st line')
print('2nd line')
print('3rd line')
```

And when I run this command in terminal:
`python3 -m pdb code.py`

I get this output:

```
1st line
2nd line
3rd line
Breakpoint 1 at /Users/mypc/code.py:2
1st line
> /Users/mypc/code.py(2)<module>()
-> print('2nd line')
(Pdb)
```

It looks like the whole code.py file is executed first and then the breakpoints are added and applied in the next cycle. How can I make sure that first breakpoints are applied and then the code starts to execute?

Expected output:

```
Breakpoint 1 at /Users/mypc/code.py:2
1st line
> /Users/mypc/code.py(2)<module>()
-> print('2nd line')
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your file (almost) anything other than `code.py`.

The problem is that `code.py` is a Python core module:

> NAME
>
> code - Utilities needed to emulate Python's interactive interpreter.
>
> MODULE REFERENCE
>
> https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/code.html

This module is [used by `pdb`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pdb.py#L77), so when you name your file `code.py` it gets imported during the startup of the `pdb` module.

Comment: Thanks.
Also how would i stop the debugger from restarting once the whole code is executed?

Comment: I'm not sure; I usually just set explicit `breakpoint()`s in my code rather than calling with `pdb`, so I'm not familiar with this mode of operation.